# Fill datagrid from webserivce

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I have an ASP.Net website, that uses a MySQL database.
First of all, because the Connect/Net of MySQL doesn't install on PC (reason unknown, no error, it just doesn't work) I'm using ODBC for the connection.
I've written some nice wrapper classes for using the database, and it's all working ok.

But now I'm adding a little Silverlight application to my website (first thing I'm making with WCF/Silverlight, without actually reading any tutorial, so let's hope for the best).

Now this application won't be anything fancy, it's only for the administrators, to read the logs, and change some configuration settings, etc, nothing fancy at all. But what it has to do is retrieve data from the services.

What I've done is a setup a service reference, and it works like a blessing, but now I'm trying to read the logs from the service, and I'm getting in trouble, because my class was never built to serialize to XML, first issue. And secondly I wouldn't know how to bind the retrieved data at the client to the datagrid.

I'm going to parse the recordset at the server so that I'll be sending a class containing an array of columns, and a multi-dimensional with the data to the client, now that's not much of a problem, I'm just mentioning it so that you can either improve or keep in mind what the data will look like.

My question: How would I bind that retrieved data to a plain <sdk:DataGrid>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own in-memory DataSet/DataTable without it being hooked up to any particular database. You can populate it yourself using anything you want in the Silverlight application. Bind your DataGrid to it after you've filled it, as you normally would do on a simple client/server ASP.NET application.

Take the retrieved data from the web service, and populate a dataset. Then bind the dataset to the datagrid. You need to write some [code-behind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221357%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) code for this, but not much. You can't do it all in the presentation layer's [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189036%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

(Edit: clarification for client/server/silverlight model)

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot, and reply back if it helped me :)

Comment: I sent a DataTable, and now I have an object that has two properties: a `System.Xml.Linq.XElement[]`, and one that returns `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`, what do I do with those to bind them to my DataGrid?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. Bind the DataGrid on the server side to your DataSet like this: `yourDataGrid.DataSource = yourDataSet.Tables("yourTable")`

Comment: I'm talking about a web service, do you even know what I mean with that? Because a web service isn't just binding server side, it's transferring server side data to the client through XML Serialization, and then the .Net platform in this case Silverlight will deserialize it, but not always into the same object.

Comment: Same thing really. In your silverlight app, take your data from wherever you got it (web service call in this case), put it in a DataSet (your job), and bind the DataGrid to the DataSet.

Comment: Not the same thing, because like I said, it converts a DataTable to a `System.Xml.Linq.XElement[]`, and you can't bind it.

Comment: Then don't bother putting it in a DataTable in the server. Send it in whatever type you want. You just need to put it into a DataTable right before you bind it to the DataGrid control.

Comment: Yes, but I can't set it as my type, because it isn't xml serializable.

Comment: Ok, so transform it into a serializable format. You don't need me to tell you this... I've already answered your original question.

Comment: No you didn't, you told me something I knew a long time ago, not what I asked for. I'll leave the question open. I wanted to know how to transfer it over a webservice.

Comment: I did answer your question. Take the retrieved data from the web service, and populate a dataset. Then bind the dataset to the datagrid.. Where is the mystery? You need to write some code-behind code for this, but not much. You can't do it all in the presentation layer XAML.

Comment: Here's an upvote to encourage you to bear with me in helping you understand what you need to do. Links updated above.

Comment: Okay, let's give you the points for the effort, but it's not what I was looking for ;)

Comment: Haha, really? Well, thanks. I'm 100% sure I've explained it. You need to get your data from the webservice in the code-behind for your silverlight application. In that code-behind, fill your dataset with data from the web service. Then bind the control to your newly filled dataset (in the code-behind).

Comment: Then you completely misunderstood the question. But it doesn't matter :).

Comment: You achieved what you wanted?

Comment: Not yet, but I'll probably binary serialize it, and then pass the byte[] and then deserialize it on the client.